# mongo filter between two timestamp dates

Tags: mongodb, timestamp, conditional-statements

I have something like this:

```
Booking.find( 
    { 
'customer' : user_id, 
'package' : { $exists: true, $ne: null } ,
'date':{ $gte:1592358731, $lt:1592358732 + (60 * 60) }
 })
.select(include_exclude) // a string with fields to exclude or include in the query
```

I realized that the date filter does not work and I debugged the query in mongo and this is what is running. What I did wrong?

```
  Mongoose: bookings.find({ customer: ObjectId("5ef01cc677608e0d44911223"), package: { '$exists': true, '$ne': null }, filter: "'date':{ $gte:1592358731, $lt:1592358732 + (60 * 60) }"}, { projection: { _id: 1, date: 1, status: 1 }})
```

I saw on this query something weird, why filter is there? filter is just the name of the constant who contains the condition string, how and why is it possible the constant name is painted as well?

**const filter: string = `'date':{ $gte:${extra_options['date'] - 1}, $lt:${extra_options['date']} + (${extra_options['duration_minutes']} * 60) }`;**

This is the part of the query I think is wrong because "filter":

**filter**: "'date':{ $gte:1592358731, $lt:1592358732 + (60 * 60) }"

Ok guys edited because I already find where is the issue, now I have to find the best solution to avoid this. As I susspect the problem was in the "filter" string printed in the query. If i add the timestamps by hand , I got this mongoose query (and it is working perfect):

```
Mongoose: bookings.find({ customer: ObjectId("5ef01cc677608e0d44916974"), package: { '$exists': true, '$ne': null }, date: { '$gte': 1592358730, '$lt': 1592358831 }}, { projection: { _id: 1, date: 1, status: 1, requesters: 1, package: 1 }})
```

Then I need to figure out how can i prevent to print the name of the const (filter) in the query.

Comment: You can include a sample input document showing the date fields you are querying on.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, but I already posted the query generated by mongo above, you can see here the timestamp:   Mongoose: bookings.find({ customer: ObjectId("5ef01cc677608e0d44911223"), package: { '$exists': true, '$ne': null }, filter: "'date':{ $gte:1592358731, $lt:1592358732 + (60 * 60) }"}, { projection: { _id: 1, date: 1, status: 1 }})

Comment: Not the query, The database - collection - document.

Comment: It is already clear for me, the problem is the wrong query, for some reason the name of the const filter is printed with the conditionals, I've explained above. Thanks